# How to calculate this limit using asymptotic formulas? $\lim_{t\to 4} \frac{4 - t}{t^\frac{1}{2} - 2}$

Tags: calculus, limits, asymptotics

How to calculate this limit using asymptotic formulas?
$$\lim_{t\to 4} \frac{4 - t}{t^\frac{1}{2} - 2}$$
My attempts were to replace variables $ 4 - t = u, u \to 0$ and use this asymptotic formula
$$ \sqrt{1 + x} = 1 + \frac{x}{2} + \frac{x^2}{8} + o(x^2) $$
But did not come to success. The answer is $-4$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The simplest way:**

You can write, for $t\neq 2$,
$$
\frac{4-t}{\sqrt{t}-2} = \frac{2^2-\sqrt{t}^2}{\sqrt{t}-2}
= \frac{(2-\sqrt{t})(2+\sqrt{t})}{\sqrt{t}-2}
= -(2+\sqrt{t})
$$
and now taking the limit should be easier.

**The way using asymptotics (Taylor expansions):** *This is not the fastest way, but is instructive.*

Taylor expansions are easier (at least for me) around 0, so let's center there. Set $u := t-4$, so that we want the limit when $u\to 0$, and
$$
\frac{4-t}{\sqrt{t}-2} = \frac{-u}{\sqrt{4+u}-2}
= \frac{-u}{2\sqrt{1+\frac{u}{4}}-2}
= \frac{-u}{2(1+\frac{u}{8}+o(u))-2}
= \frac{-u}{\frac{u}{4}+o(u)}
= \frac{-4}{1+o(1)}
$$
giving that the limit is indeed $-4$, as $1+o(1)\to 1$. Here, we used the standard Taylor expansion around $0$, $(1+u)^a = 1+au+o(u)$; i.e., the one you mentioned in your question.

Comment: This is not an answer.

Comment: @lonestudent I see. Let me edit to specifically use asymptotic fomulae, as requested.

Comment: @lonestudent What about now? Thanks for making sure I did answer the specific question, instead of just writing "the simplest way to get the limit."

Comment: Probably your reputation is enough to see my deleted answer...  After reading the question thoroughly, I deleted it.  Your answer, of course, deserves upvote. $\large{\color{red}{\text{+1.}}}$

Comment: @lonestudent I, to my shame, had read the question too quickly, and had missed the part specifically asking about using asymptotics (Taylor expansions). Thanks for commenting on that to point it out.

Comment: @ClementC. You were able to solve the problem through the Taylor series because you were able to reduce the coefficients so that the zero coefficients were reduced. I mean these things $\frac{-u}{\color{red}{2}(1+\frac{u}{8}+o(u))-\color{red}{2}}$?

Comment: @heiverjust Not sure what you mean by "the zero coefficients were reduced" here? Do you mean the fact that in the denominator the constant coefficient ($2\cdot 1$ gets cancelled out by the $-2$?

Comment: @ClementC.  "Do you mean the fact that in the denominator the constant coefficient (2⋅1 gets cancelled out by the −2?" - Yes, I do.

Comment: @heiverjust Yes, then; this is crucial for the proof to go through (and the limit to be what it is). If the constant term in the denominator didn't cancel, the simplification by a factor $u$ in the numerator and denominator wouldn't be possible (and overall the limit would be $0$, not $-4$).

Answer (score 0):

We first compute the numerator and denominator limit
Reducing to one denominator
lim for x = 4 (-2 is the root of x)
Answer: -4

Comment: This doesn't make sense. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) instead.